# How can I get Maven to write a property into a property file at package time?

Tags: java, maven-2, teamcity

For continuous integration I am using Maven 2 and TeamCity 5.1.2. My builder number is defined by the pattern `%maven.project.version%.{0}`, and this is exported to Maven build script as `${build.number}`

When the build creates the jar file I would like the jar to contain a property file with this information inside:

```
build.number=#1.1-SNAPSHOT.106
```

This is so that the build number is available for display etc at runtime.

Comment: Here is almost exactly the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532135/using-maven-to-output-the-version-number-to-a-text-file

Comment: almost, but not exactly. The solution in the post referred to by Seanizer gets me a long way down the road. Now I have in my properties file after the build completes: build.number=%maven.project.version%.113.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the comment, it sounds like %maven.project.version% is not being replaced by TeamCity.  You're getting the build job number, but not getting the value for the maven ID.

I would look at potentially doing this in two parts.

Can ${build.number} only contain the actual build number, instead of %maven.project.version%?

If so, you should be able to have your properties file say:

```
build.number=#${project.version}.${build.number}
```

In theory that would produce:

```
build.number=#1.1-SNAPSHOT.106
```

But not having worked with TeamCity, this is just a theory.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a copy of the property file with a placeholder for the build number

```
build.number=${build.number}
```

Than copy with filtering enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
build.number=${buildNumber}
```

where `${buildNumber}` is place holder for Maven to add the next number.