# Maven filter resources and adding project version

Tags: maven-2

This is an easy filter approach to write the project version into a file.

```
<build>
 <resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.version</include>
    </includes>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
 </resources>
</build>
```

This is the project structure (left out the unintresting parts)

```
├───src
│   └───main
│       ├───java
│       │   └─── [...]
│       └───webapp
│           ├───META-INF
│           └───WEB-INF
│               ├───cfg
│               └───portal.version
└─── pom.xml
```

The content of `portal.version`

```
${project.version}
```

This should be replaced with the artifact version of the `pom.xml`, but unfortunately nothing happens. Whats wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: I would give you more than one point just for the question. Navigating through the maven documentation is a hell, and usually results in a long and complex xml snippet. This is clear, quick and immediate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify resource element, the result filtered content is copied into a target/classes folder. To filter web app resources you could configure maven-war-plugin.

Though to get the version, in most cases it is better to read a standard Maven property file in your application, e.g. `META-INF\maven\<groupId>\<artifactId>\pom.properties`

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to bind maven that closely to my application.

Comment: This property file is not available in the classpath when you run your application in your IDE - reading works only in the deployed runtime context outside your IDE.
maven/.../pom.properties is only build into the jar or war artifact.

Answer (score 2):

To filter web resources, you can use [the filtering capabilities of the war plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is solved in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31149696/9737735) and also there's an additional step, you have to include this under *maven-resources-plugin*:

```
<delimiters>
    <delimiter>${*}</delimiter>
</delimiters>
```

At least that worked for me and I had the exact same issue as you.