# Replace task in Maven Antrun Plugin

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I am using antrun plugin in my maven build to replace a token **@version@** in some of the JSP files with the application version.
This is what I am doing:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
                 <target>
                      <echo>${displayVersion}</echo>
                      <replace file="src/main/webapp/admin/decorators/default.jsp" token="@version@" value="${displayVersion}"/>
                 </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I am passing **displayVersion** as a parameter to maven

`mvn clean install -DdisplayVersion="Version-1.1"`

And this is the console output for **Antrun Plugin**

```
[INFO] [antrun:run {execution: default}]
[INFO] [antrun:run {execution: default}]  
[INFO] Executing tasks  
main:  
[echo] 9.4_70  
[INFO] Executed tasks
```

Although the property is being echoed properly, it's not substituted in my JSP.
The **@version@** token is replaced by **{displayVersion}** and not it's actual value.

Comment: In the antrun configuration you posted you actually use `value="${display}"` and not `value="${displayVersion}"`, is it a typo in the original code or a cut'n'paste issue?

Comment: Its a typo... my Bad. I have edited the question to rectify the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Maven Resources Filtering as Aaron suggested and [set the delimiters](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#delimiters) in the Maven Resource Plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
      <delimiters>
        <!-- enable maven's standard delimiters -->
        <delimiter>${*}</delimiter>
        <!-- enable your @delimiters@ -->
        <delimiter>@</delimiter>
      </delimiters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Maven resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) can replace variables in resources; so if you deliver the JSP (instead of compiling it with the jspc plugin), you can simply let the resource plugin do the work while it copies resources by [enabling filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

Comment: Aaron, I am aware about the Maven resource filtering. But I am migrating from AMT to MAVEN and the token I use is @ -- **@version@** and I believe for Maven Resource filtering I need to change it to **${version}**  Now, there are a lot of files in which I need to replace this token, and I can't go and make it **${version}**.  Is there any way by which I can filter **@version@** with Maven Resource Filtering

Comment: Try Sean's solution. Which IDE are you using? In Eclipse, you can do a global search'n'replace over all files.