# Maven build number plugin, how to save the build number in a file?

Tags: maven, build, maven-plugin, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I've a Java project using Spring Framework and Git and I wanted to display a build number. I found the [Build Number Maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/). With Git the build number is a Git hash. I dislike that and I thought a date was much more expressive.

I found this [excellent blog article](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/06/04/maven-automatic-build-versioning-and-git-against-subversion/) explaining how to use build number plugin with a different profile for SVN and Git. Since I just use Git, instead of creating a new profile, I just copied the plugin part in my build tag.

When I run "mvn package" it tells me:

```
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.0:create (default) @ sherd ---
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: 2011-08-04_21-48_stivlo at timestamp: 1312487296631
```

Which looks ok, but I wonder, where is it stored? "git status" doesn't detect any new file and it seems it's not in target/ too (target/ is in my .gitignore).

Maybe I've to change the configuration to store the build number in a file? How can I use the build number value?

---

Thanks to the hint of Michael-O, I read the chapter about [how to filter resource files in Maven Getting Started Guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_filter_resource_files). I've created a file application.properties in src/main/resources/properties/application.properties with the following contents:

```
# application properties
application.name=${pom.name}
application.version=${pom.version}
application.build=${buildNumber}
```

I've added the following XML snippet within my build section:

```xml
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources/properties</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Now when I call from command line "mvn package", this property file gets saved in target/classes/properties/application.properties, for instance with the following contents:

```xml
# application properties
application.name=Sherd Control Panel
application.version=1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
application.build=2011-08-05_05-55_stivlo
```

Everything works fine from command line, but, sigh, m2eclipse gives Build errors:

```xml
05/08/11 6.05.03 CEST: Build errors for obliquid-cp; 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal
org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.0:create (default) on project 
sherd: Cannot get the branch information from the scm repository : 
Exception while executing SCM command.
```

For some reason m2eclipse tries to connect to my repository, but it can't because it's a Git repository accessed with SSH and a private key. I wonder if I can tell m2eclipse to not connect to Git.

---

After more digging I found about revisionOnScmFailure option, set it to true and now also m2eclipse works. For reference, here is the full configuration of buildnumber maven plugin that I used (it goes in pom.xml in the build / plugins section).

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <doCheck>false</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
         <revisionOnScmFailure>true</revisionOnScmFailure>
        <format>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm}_{1}</format>
        <items>
            <item>timestamp</item>
            <item>${user.name}</item>
        </items>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store it in a filtered properties file.  See [Using maven to output the version number to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532135/using-maven-to-output-the-version-number-to-a-text-file)

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't set `revisionOnScmFailure` option to `true`, it doesn't expect a boolean. Set it to revision string you want to use when SCM is unavailable, like `na` or like that. It doesn't matter for your case since you override the build number format but it would be more correct.

See [buildnumber-maven-plugin docs](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/create-mojo.html#revisionOnScmFailure).

Comment: Thanks, i could not get the plugin to work when building through Netbeans on Mac OS X 10.10, but through the command line it builds fine. Setting this property let me continue working through the IDE and the Jenkins server obviously works too.

Answer (score 3):

I could not reproduce the problem reported by the OP. In my case both command line and m2eclipse work fine and the file is generated correctly in the **target/classes** folder. The answer provided by @KasunBG is incorrect. The buildNumber.properties is generated only if you use the following:

```xml
        <format>{0,number}</format>
        <items>
            <item>buildNumber</item>
        </items>
```

buildNumber.properties is used to store a number which can be incremented. For this reason ( I think ) the plugin doesn't generate this file if you use timestamp/scmVersion etc.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/create-mojo.html#buildNumberPropertiesFileLocation) page says that the properties files is stored at `${basedir}/buildNumber.properties`, which is created when the `buildnumber:create` phase is ran.

Comment: however it doesn't create that file, at least with my configuration. I had a partial success by filtering properties files, but I ran into another problem as in my updated question.

Comment: have you tried manually creating the file, and adding a starting buildNumber there first? 
Do that and, do your thing and then check whether the number is incremented. Make sure you fulfilled the requirements it asked for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to create an empty buildNumber.properties file, and execute buildnumber:create and nothing happens, then I tried to put inside a 1, execute a buildnumber:create and nothing happened. In the meantime, I just found the solution to the last problem using filtered properties. I am going to update my question with the full solution.

Comment: @stivlo When you use filtered properties your properties file contains the string `foo=${buildNumber}` and changes the variable only for the built artifact. What if I am in development mode and want to get the build number from the properties file but not the `${buildNumber}` string?