# How to get the SVN buildnumber of a particular branch in Maven

Tags: java, svn, maven, branch

I do SVN check out for a tree of multiple branches, and I use the buildnumber plugin to get the SVN revision with "javasvn" implementation provider.

When I try to build a particular branch, it seems that Maven retrieves the revision of the top level folder of the tree, not the revision of that particular branch.

For example: 
root revision no.: 100 
root/branch1 revision no.: 99 
root/branch2 revision no.: 97

In my case, when building branch1, I need 99 for buildnumber, not 100.

I use SVN 1.7.

Here is how I configure the plugin:

```
<build>

    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-SVN${buildNumber}</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                <providerImplementations>
                    <svn>javasvn</svn>
                </providerImplementations>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Any idea is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the pom.xml file ? How you configured buildnumber plugin and how does your scm entry look like?

Comment: You know that the revision is assigned globally over the entire repo?

Comment: @Michael-O, can you please add a reference for this?

Comment: @HaithamSweilem The reference for Subversion is the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.basic.in-action.revs) furthermore that the revision number is defined globally for the whole repository and **not** for a branch etc. should be known. Apart from that why do you need the revision of the branch?

Comment: @khmarbaise Then how do the builds from branch are done, if that is the case? I guess, there should be some where to put a flag to pickup revision number of `branch` and not `root`.

Comment: If you have a branch than your version should give hint about that. From trunk 1.0.0.0 from branch 1.0.X.0 if you are following a bug fixing branch pattern. During a release of an artifact an svn tag is created which has the relationship to the branch. Afterwards the branch will be merged back into trunk and deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the **useLastCommittedRevision** configuration which is set to false by default. This should grab the *last committed revision* instead of the repository revision on the specific module where the pom builds from.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how we do it in our project:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532135/using-maven-to-output-the-version-number-to-a-text-file -->
                            <!-- Safety -->
                            <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}"/>

                            <exec executable="svn" output="${basedir}/src/main/filters/svn.properties" dir="..">
                                <arg value="info"/>
                            </exec>
                            <replace file="${basedir}/src/main/filters/svn.properties" token="Last Changed Rev"
                                     value="Last.Changed.Rev"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

That outputs a line in `src/main/filters/svn.properties` that has `Last.Changed.Rev: 22479` in it.  We rename `Last Changed Rev` to `Last.Changed.Rev` so it's a valid variable name.  You can then use that as a filter in other files.  You may not need it as a filter, but maybe this example will help you for your needs.