# how to reference maven properties in other files

Tags: eclipse, maven, properties, reference, pom.xml

I have a simple problem (maybe not that simple...) for which I couldn't find a solution. I have created a maven project in eclipse and set a line in the pom like this

```
<name>myTestProject</name>
```

When I build the project, a myTestProject.jar is correctly generated. Plus, I want my jar to have input parameters, so I created in the project a .bat and a .sh with the line

```
"java -jar myTestProject.jar input1 input2 ..."
```

Now, if I want my target name to change along time, in order not to modify the .bat and .sh each time I have changed the lines according to the maven references like this:

```
"java -jar ${project.name}.jar input1 input2 ..."
```

But this does not work; the files are just copied but not processed on compilation time, hence neither the .bat nor the .sh will run the jar.

Is there a way to make maven process these files and change the tags for the correct values when compiling?

Thanks in advance,

Miguel.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3532280/1089062

Comment: Thanks a lot, Will! That was exactly what I was looking for, filtering.