# properties-maven-plugin System properties

Tags: maven, plugins, properties

System.getProperty("hello.world.two") returns null. Tried compile/initialize/package phase.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- any phase before your app deploys -->
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>hello.world.two</name>
                        <value>Hello World!</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: When did you call `System.getProperty("hello.world.two")`? During the Maven build? In your application at run-time?

Comment: During application run-time

Comment: Then this is expected: during the Maven build, the system property is set. But your application is ran in another VM. Instead, you can write this property to a text file and read this file in your app.

Comment: How to write this  property to a text file.

Comment: Refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3532135/1743880): this talks about the project version but it works for any property.

Comment: Thanks. Seems writing the  property to a text file needs maven-resources-plugin

Comment: Is there a way (maven plugin)  to read the Maven build system property  using System.getProperty()  in application runtime directly without writing to a file.

Comment: No: it is different VM executions so different system properties.

Comment: maven-surefire-plugin;s systemPropertyVariables supports this use case. But surefire-plugin used for unit testing,  I need it for application.

Comment: What is exactly the purpose you need the property for? Thought about `src/main/resources` folder?

Comment: We have couple of properties file for each application. We need to read the property file name for every application.   Application1 has user.properties1 and  Application2 has user.properties2.  Based on this name(property file name) we will load the property file for each application.

Comment: All the properties files are in the src/main/resources folder