# Using @project.version@ with Liquibase in a multimodule Maven project

Tags: java, maven, liquibase

It was a little bit hard to come up with a meaningful title, hope it will become clear enough after the explanation. I have searched through a number of Qs and As on SO, and they were all very close to the problem I am experiencing, but still not close enough.

In general, what I want to accomplish is to store project version in DB by accessing the maven property `@project.version@` from a `.csv` file which is loaded by a Liquibase script.
My maven project structure looks like this:

```
parentModule
pom.xml
|
---moduleA
   |__pom.xml
---moduleB
   |__pom.xml
---moduleC
   |__pom.xml
...
```

Pom.xml are defined as:

```
**PARENT POM**
<project ...>

  <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>parent</name>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
         <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <modules>
        <module>moduleA</module>
        <module>moduleB</module>
        <module>moduleC</module>
        ...
  </modules>

  <build>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
----------------------------------------------------------------------

**CHILD POM**
<project ...>
    <artifactId>moduleC</artifactId>
    <name>moduleC</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      ...
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
 <build>
   <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>moduleC/src/main/resources/db/changelog/</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/app_version.csv/</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
 </build>
</project>
```

Liquibase scripts are defined in `moduleC/src/main/resources/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml` etc., while the .csv files with initial values are located in `moduleC/src/main/resources/db/users.csv` etc. In one of those csv files, I want to push `@project.version@` value, like this:

```
id;app_key;app_value;created_by;last_modified_by
1;app-version;@project.version@;system;system
```

Since that file is located in `moduleC`, I used maven resource filtering even in`parentModule` `<build/>` to filter that file so it can resolve `@project.version@` property, but with no luck:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>moduleC/src/main/resources/db/changelog/</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/app_version.csv/</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

There are errors, one that says that master changelog cannot be found, while in other cases just string value `@project.version@` is stored. Seems to me I should include `app_version.csv` and its location (`moduleC`) as resource inside `<build>` tag withing parentModule pom.xml, but every combination of referencing it fails. Is there a solution to reference it properly (either from parentModule or moduleC pom.xml) or there might be an easier way to store `@project.version@` with liquibase?

Comment: Is `project.version` changes frequently? Perhaps you could store it as a property in liquibase changeLog file and add it to your changets?

Comment: The liquibase changelog can contain information about version, seems that you are repeating this functionality. How do you run liquibase? Have you inspected your target folder to verifiy whether resource filtering works?

Comment: can you provide sample project somewhere (github)?

Comment: 1. (and as a rule of thumb): Do things in your parent pom, which are common to all/most of the children (e.g. plugin configuration, dependency management... if you have a <execution> element in your parent pom, be aware of what you do) 2. Do child specific things in child poms (override versions/properties/configuration)...use execution(s of liquibase) here, also "resource filtering"! 3. Refer to the correct resources! (relatively to the actual pom ...in `moduleC/pom.xml` it should be `src/main/...` not `moduleC/src/...` and in what world `users.csv`is matched by `**/app_version.csv`?)

Comment: ...and 4. where's actually your liquibase-execution (pom element)? (2.: resource filtering can also be turned on (for all children) in the parent pom, but still "relatively"  `src/main/...` not `C:\Users\xerx593\myprojects\...` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am extremely sorry for not replying on time, was temporarily removed from the project after posting the question and was not able to access the git repository due to change of location. So far, I have tried all of the proposed actions, but with no result. In the end, what I found to work was an accepted answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532135/using-maven-to-output-the-version-number-to-a-text-file). I have added the build block inside mavenC module pom.xml and it worked. Nevertheless, thank you all immensely for posting and helping.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Looks like you're using the wrong syntax for filtering in the CSV-file. Instead of using `@project.version@`, try `${project.version}` instead:</s>

Check the `<directory>moduleC/src/main/resources/...</directory>`, if the resources plugin lives in the child POM of moduleC then there is no need for the prefix.

Try replacing with `<directory>src/main/resources/..</directory>`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the [maven-replacer-plugin](https://code.google.com/archive/p/maven-replacer-plugin/wikis/UsageGuide.wiki) in your build cycle. It will be configured to process the 'app_version.csv' file and output the substituted file content to the 'target/classes' folder. The subsequent packaging phase will ensure the csv file with the current pom version will be bundled into the artifact that the liquidbase tool then handles.

Answer (score 1):

Resources filtering of a module should be in the build of the module itself.
The project.version property will be inherited from the parent.
Be careful so the filtering does not mess with your xml files.
I think the syntax should be ${project.version}

Can you share your liquibase maven plugin configuration ? 
The markup  should point to your master changelog.

Here is two other solutions:
Another solution would be to create a liquibase changeset every time you create a new version. You can do it programmatically using liquibase java SDK in a spring component which run on startup of your project or create the changeset yourself.

Another solution would be to use Spring Boot Actuator to retrieve project version.
For this you need to add `<goal>build-info</goal>` in the goals of spring-boot-maven-plugin