# How to get properties in Multi modules maven project

Tags: maven, pom.xml, multi-module

I have two maven applications A and B which both use a common module C.
In this last I want to create an API which return the version of the deployed app "/deployedVersion" I'm such a way that "appA/deployedVersion" will return the version of appA and the same for appB
The version's number of appA and appB are  in pom.xml of the two app.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using maven to output the version number to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532135/using-maven-to-output-the-version-number-to-a-text-file)

Comment: Once you have the version number in a file you can return it to the caller.

Comment: Another option is [spring-boot-actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html) if you already use spring-boot.

Comment: i'm not sure. I have to get the version number with an API, not in a text file and the api is in the C module but the version number in the pom of applications which use the C module

Comment: The code that implements the API can read the file, any file in the classpath.

Comment: you're right. so i have to put the code in the pom.xml of my A and B applications ? and read the file generate in the  module API ?